# Как отследить комбинацию клавиш в Java?

Tags: java

Подскажите, как отследить комбинацию клавиш **Ctrl+Enter** в Java.

На данный момент получается отловить только нажатие Ctrl или Enter

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
   if (e.getKeyCode() == 17) {
      System.out.println("111");
   }
}
```

Comment: В книжке Хорстмана в 1 томе (8 глава кажется) есть отличный пример, как работать с клавишами, как перехватывать нажатия.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER && e.isControlDown()) {
                System.out.println("Hello");
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Спасибо! Воспользовался данным кодом!